# Reference Field in Table1 From Table2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have two tables each with a separate DataSource.  Table1 has a total column at the bottom.  In my Table2, I want to point a row in Table2 to the Total column in DataSet1.  I tried using this: which is field name, and dataset name.  What would allow this to happen if at all?

```
=Sum(Fields!TotalCount.Value, "SalesTotals")
```

Comment: ..  I pretty much feel this is possible to do, but more explantion needed

Comment: Sure, what information should I provide in order for a full picture of understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work just fine...or to reference a total column in the other table, you can reference the report item itself.  For example, if the name of the cell that holds the totals in Table1 is txtTable1Total, then your formula in the cell in Table2 would look like this:

```
=ReportItems!txtTable1Total.Value
```