# Sum Expression Column from 2 Tables

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

Pointing back to a previous post I had here:
[Reference Field in Table1 From Table2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098718/reference-field-in-table1-from-table2/21102554#21102554)

I know just realized I need to take this a step further, and now sum my expression column.  I tried and both of those threw an error of: [rsAggregateReportItemInBody] The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox14.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses an aggregate function on a report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers.  Can someone help out a noob again :)

```
=SUM(ReportItems!Textbox54+ReportItems!Textbox7)
=ReportItems!Textbox54+ReportItems!Textbox7
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just write an expression that retrieves the same value as whatever is in textbox54 or textbox7 by referencing their dataset?

Comment: If I use =Fields!Textbox7.Value+Fields!Textbox54.Value I get an error of unknown collection member.  Is that what you were trying to tell me to do?

Comment: What is the expression in Textbox7?  I'm suggesting you try copying the expression out of there and adapting it to use in the new textbox you are trying to populate rather than referencing the textbox.

Comment: Textbox7 contains this expression:
=Fields!ACount.Value/ReportItems!BCount.Value
*If I adapt the function in both of the textboxes and use a SUM to try to get the total in the column I want it gives an inaccurate Total Column.